# Building and installing JAGS locally

Tags: r, linux, autotools, jags

I'm trying to build and install JAGS on a cluster that uses GPFS as its filesystem.  I'm running into problems with the configure script:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/JAGS/ --with-lapack=/cm/shared/apps/lapack/gcc/64/3.6.0/liblapack.so
```

Error:

```
configure: error: "You need to install the LAPACK library"
```

I'm specifying the location of the dynamic library, but the script doesn't accept that it exists on the system.  What is the cause of this?

Comment: Try `./configure --help`. It should tell you how to do it. *"... I'm specifying the location of the dynamic library..."* - It likely needs headers and library; maybe something like `--lapack=/usr/local/cm/` (after an install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I needed to link to BLAS by using the "--with-blas" flag.  The configure script does not have an error message for a missing BLAS link, it instead treats it as a missing reference to the LAPACK library.